# Javascript Matrix: horizontal and vertical numbering for locating a value in a given a,b coordinate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a requirement where I need to print something, lets say in a grid or square shape like below

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Not all rows and columns will have values. so I need to add ascending numbers from 0 both vertically and horizontally to find out where the value is missing and log it.

Expected is

```
5*****
4****N
3***NN
2**NNN
1*NNNN
012345
```

Here N is an empty value

Now considering vertical as Y and horizontal numbers as X. With X,Y being (3,1) there is no value.

So first I started working on printing this pattern, so I tried below

```js
const n = 5;

for(let i = n; i>=0; i--){
   for(let j = 0; j<=i; j++){
    if(j!=0){
       process.stdout.write("*")
    }else{
      process.stdout.write(i)
    }
 }
  console.log(); // just for newline
}
```

I researched online and came up with above code that's actually close but I'm facing some issues

1. When I run this in local, it throws The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type number (5). I cannot use document.write because I'm doing this in nodejs, what is the workaround to print without /n - newline that console.log adds by default?
2. Something is going wrong with horizontal numbering while the vertical seems fine. What am i doing wrong?
3. Is there a way to do this without 2 loops? It would be great if someone can give me a better code with less complexity

again to be precise, I'm trying to print this

```
5*****
4****
3***
2**
1*
012345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another attempt. Instead of directly writing to stdout, accumulate the table into an array and send the array to `console.log`. Also, it uses only a single loop.

```js
function makeTable(limit) {
  let rows = [];
  let last = [];
  let i = limit;
  while (i >= 0) {
    let stars = new Array(i).fill('*');
    if (i > 0) {
      rows.push([i].concat(stars).join(''));
    }
    last.push(i);
    i -= 1;
  }
  return rows.concat(last.reverse().join('')).join('\n');
}

console.log(makeTable(5));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. :)